# Python 3.x: Conditional multiplying elements of list

Tags: python-3.x, list

How can I multiply certain numbers in lists? For example:

```
if i >= 3:
    result = [i* 3 for i in list]
if i < 3:
    result = [i * 2 for i in list]
``
```

I already tried with following func and it didnt work out:

```
def special_multiply(list, multiplicator,multiplicator_2):
    for i in list:
        if i >= 3:
            result = [i* multiplicator for i in list]
        if i < 3:
            result = [i * multiplicator_2 for i in list]
        return result

print("Special multiply:", special_multiply([1,2,3,4,5,6],2,3))
I expected following output:[2,4,9,12,15,18]
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
def special_multiply(parameterList, multi, multi2):
    returnList = []
    for i in parameterList:
        if i >=3:
            returnList.append(i*multi2)
        else:
            returnList.append(i*multi)
return returnList
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation to the source code explaining how it solves the problem.